# Connecting plasms in ECTO

Tags: ros, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a repository for a new visual processing pipeline which should be able to accommodate several different functionality (data capture, filtering, segmentation, etc) and in each function it should also be able to support several different implementations so that when the system is up and running it can select which implementation may best suit the current process.

I am wondering if I should implement this as each function as a plasm but this brings up the question can I connect multiple plasms in ECTO to make the final pipeline or must everything be connected together in one plasm?

I have gotten my cell structure set up the way that we want it to be I am not just trying to figure out how to best set up the plasms.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59156/connecting-plasms-in-ecto/) by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard approach to this is to implement these pieces as an [ecto blackbox](http://plasmodic.github.com/ecto/ecto/usage/techniques/black_box.html), and then string the blackbox items together to get a plasm. As far as I know, you can only have 1 plasm. Within the object recognition kitchen (ORK), each of the pipelines is implemented as a blackbox, so those might serve as some additional examples.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on 2013-03-25**:
So the idea would be to encapsulate each function and its varying implementations into a black box and then connect all of the black boxes together into one core plasm which would run the whole system?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-26**:
Yep. That's the idea. The blackbox is basically just a cell, containing lots of other cells within.

**Comment by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on 2013-03-26**:
Thank you so much for all your assistance with getting all of this set up and running!